# How to output the results with batch scripts?

Tags: batch-file

This is the original:

> 1:80
>   1:81
>   1:82
>   1:83

I want to use the batch as the results:

> 1:80,
>   1:81,
>   1:82,
>   1:83

This is my batch file. Something seems wrong:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /f "delims" %%i in {*.txt} 
    do echo %%i,
 for /f "delims" %%j in (*.txt) do (
     set var=%%j
     echo !var!
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

some syntax problems with `for`:

1. it is `"delims="` for no delimiters
2. it is `(*.txt)`, not `{*.txt}`
3. you missed the closing `)` with your second `for`statement

and a logical problem: your second `for` does process all lines again, not only the last, like I think, you intend.

Comment: thanks, but when i modified and output the batch, it has same value, like:
1:80,
1:81,
1:82,
1:83,
1:83